# Why contract function multiply always returns 0

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development

I have setup my private blockchain for testing. And created and deployed following contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.11;

contract Multiply7 {
   event Print(uint);
   function multiply(uint input) returns (uint) {
      Print(input * 7);
      return input * 7;
   }
}
```

Generated `abi` and `code` using `solc`:

```
6060604052341561000c57fe5b5b60df8061001b6000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063c6888fa114603a575bfe5b3415604157fe5b60556004808035906020019091905050606b565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60007f24abdb5865df5079dcc5ac590ff6f01d5c16edbc5fab4e195d9febd1114503da600783026040518082815260200191505060405180910390a16007820290505b9190505600a165627a7a7230582089c25c3ddf32ed3ef55436bff071176b9b807c9cac456721766027c17261657e0029
```

ABI here:

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"input","type":"uint256"}],"name":"multiply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Print","type":"event"}]
```

Deployed contract and got transaction receipt:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], data: code})
contractAddress = eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x2d1483f05c0420284ccc4f1ad4003466cc6b51e119c1009d6edfd966a9ec399f').contractAddress
//0x84a56a919232516d2f928ed1b66423e974de4c8b
```

Now I am accessing this contract:

```
myContract = eth.contract(abi)
contract = myContract.at('0x84a56a919232516d2f928ed1b66423e974de4c8b')
contract.multiple.call(6) // always returns 0
```

When I paste `code` from example from [here](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/contracts.html) everything works just fine.

I am not understanding what is the problem with my approach. My solc code and abi are correct? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you mark your `multiply(...)` function with a `constant` modifier, your call should work. Otherwise you have to send a transaction to execute your `multiply(...)` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing gaslimit:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], data: code, gas: 100000})
```

Edit:

As default gas is `90000` which may be less for transaction with data. Check `eth.getCode('0x84a56a919232516d2f928ed1b66423e974de4c8b')` before you access the contract. If it doesn't return your contract code, contract wasn't deployed properly.

Comment: What this has to do with gas limit?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Because default gas in `sendTransaction` is `90000`, which is enough for transaction with no data but fails for contract creation (which may take more than default gas)

Comment: hmm.. that may be the case if the contract is deployed without any data. You can edit the answer explaining others the logic behind your statement. Upvoted. :)

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Added explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `contract.multiply.call(6)` not `contract.multipl`**e**

Comment: I think that was question typo. `contract.multiply.call(6)` doesn't work as he says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is upon creation of your contract you do not send enough gas. By default it is 90000 ( for [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e61035c5a3630e4f6fd0fb3e5346a4eed8cedc80/internal/ethapi/api.go#L50) ) or the results given after creating it are

`Transaction cost: 112321 gas. 
 Execution cost: 44689 gas.`

As you can see more gas are required to create the contract than the default value.

You have to send more gas during your transaction in order to make the creation successful by adding the following parameter :

`eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], data: code, gas: 200000})`

And speaking about gas you should mark your method `constant` like this

`function multiply (uint input) constant returns (uint)`

Constant indicates that your function is not supposed to modify the states, and no gas will be used because it allows to the function to be executed locally/off blockchain in your node.